# How to convert time analysis to O(n)?

Tags: big-o

Rookie computer science student here, have a question I'm having some trouble answering.

I have a tree traversal algorithm, the time performance of which is O(bm) where b is the branching factor and m is the max depth of the tree. I was wondering how one takes this and converts it into standard asymptotic time analysis (IE O(n), O(n^2), etc).

Same question for a different algorithm I have which is O(b^m).

I have gone through my textbook extensively and not found a clear answer about this. Asymptotic time analysis usually relates to input (n) but I'm not sure what n would mean in this instance. I suppose it would be m?

In general, what do you do when you have multiple inputs?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start with building a recurrence.  For example, let us consider binary search.  The recurrence comes as: T(n) = T(n/2) + c.  When you solve it, you will get

```
T(n) = T(n/2) + c
     = T(n/4) + c + c
     = T(n/8) + c + c + c
     ...
     = T(n/2^k) + kc
```

The recurrence is solved when n = 2^k or k = log_2(n).  So, the complexity is c.log_2(n)

Now, let us look at another situation where the input is divided into 5 parts, and the results combined in linear time.  This recurrence will be

```
T(n) = 5T(n/5) + n
     = 5^2T(n/5^2) + 2n
     ...
     = 5^kT(n/5^k) + kn
```

This will stop when n = 5^k or k = log_5(n).  So, substituting above, the complexity is: n.log_5(n).

I guess you should be able to take it from here on.

Comment: Thank you very much for your thoughtful answer, but I'm still confused. 

In my particular case, what is n? Is n the branching factor or the max depth? 

I understand how to find big O for sorting algorithms because n is clearly the number of items being sorted, but I don't understand how to for a traversal algorithm, where n is unclear. This is what I am trying to clarify.

Comment: n is the number of elements you are operating on.  In the first case (binary search), n is the number of elements being searched.  In the second case, n is again the number of elements that you are dividing into 5 and operating on those groups by further subdividing into five each.  Your big-Oh analysis will depend on the amount of time to do the division (constant), time to operate on the divided parts, and time to combine the result.  In the first example, the time to divide into two is constant.  You look at only one of the two partitions (hence T(n/2)), and no extra time to combine result.

Comment: In the second example, you have five partitions of 1/5 each, giving 5T(n/5) and you go over each partition to combine the result (5.n/5 > n).  You are looking for depth of the tree (log_5(n)) as well as the time to divide and conquer (n at each level).  So, the time to divide and conquer (at each level) multiplied by the number of levels (depth of tree) gives you the overall time.  Hope that helps.